# Primality test using Chebyshev and Legendre polynomials

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, examples-counterexamples, primality-test

Inspired by Theorem 5 in [this paper](http://icm.mcs.kent.edu/reports/1999/chebpol.pdf) I have formulated the following claim :

> Let $n$ be an odd number and $n>1$ . Let $T_n(x)$ be [Chebyshev polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) of the first kind and let $P_n(x)$ be [Legendre polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials) , then $n$ is a prime number if and only if the following congruences hold simultaneously
>
> $\bullet \: T_n(3) \equiv 3 \pmod n$
>
> $\bullet \: P_n(3) \equiv 3 \pmod n$

You can run this test [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJzLszU2tOblykzT0PDNT9EoyM9JzkhNqizOSC3TyNMx1DHW1MnTtLUFUkhKclLTU_NSilKBKhDyBUWZeSUaSkAqN1UJzk3Ozy3IL84sAQphFbMGABShKN4=&lang=gp) .

I was searching for pseudoprimes using the following PARI/GP program :

```
CL(lb,ub)=
{
forstep(n=lb,ub,[2],
if(!ispseudoprime(n), 
if((Mod(polchebyshev(n,1,3),n)==3), 
if((Mod(pollegendre(n,3),n)==3),print(n)))))
}
```

I have tested this claim up to $1.4 \cdot 10^6$ and there were no counterexamples .

*Question :* Can you provide a proof or a counterexample for the claim given above ?

Comment: I tried sage cell on 5394826801 and got an error message. I was trying to find out if it can deal with Carmichael numbers. I got this error mesg "PARI/GP interpreter crashed -- automatically restarting.
***   at top-level: if((Mod(polchebyshev(n,1,3),n)==3),if((Mo
  ***                                      ^--------------------
  ***   incorrect type in gtos [integer expected] (t_POL)."

Comment: @user25406 We have 2 min CPU time limit per computation . The number 5394826801 is too big .

Comment: can you please explain the motivation of adding the Legendre polynomial condition to get a primality test? thanks.

Comment: @user25406 The main idea behind this test is essentially similar to the idea behind [Baillie-PSW primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baillie%E2%80%93PSW_primality_test) . I made the assumption that list of Chebyshev pseudoprimes base 3 and a list of Legendre pseudoprimes base 3 have no overlap .

Answer (score 6):

This is a partial answer.

This answer proves that if $n$ is an odd prime, then $P_n(3)\equiv 3\pmod n$.

Using that $\binom nk\equiv 0\pmod n$ for $1\le k\le n-1$, we have
$$\begin{align}P_n(3)&=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom nk^2(3-1)^{n-k}(3+1)^k\\\\&=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom nk^2\cdot 2^{n-k}\cdot 2^{2k}\\\\&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom nk^2\cdot 2^k\\\\&\equiv \binom n0^2\cdot 2^0+\binom nn^2\cdot 2^n\quad\pmod n\\\\&\equiv 1+2^n\quad\pmod n\end{align}$$

Now, since $\frac{n^2-1}{4}$ is even when $n$ is odd, we have
$$\begin{align}P_n(3)&\equiv 1+2^n\equiv 1+2\cdot\left(2^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\right)^2\equiv 1+2\cdot \left((-1)^{\frac{n^2-1}{8}}\right)^2\equiv 1+2\cdot (-1)^{\frac{n^2-1}{4}}\\\\&\equiv 3\pmod n\qquad\blacksquare\end{align}$$

---

According to Theorem 5 in the paper you showed, we can say that if $n$ is an odd prime, then $T_n(3)\equiv 3\pmod n$.

Therefore, we can say that if $n$ is an odd prime, then $T_n(3)\equiv P_n(3)\equiv 3\pmod n$.